# Using Twilio SIP Trunk on FusionPBX

Tags: twilio, fusionpbx

Has anyone attempted to use Twilio SIP Trunks with FusionPBX?

I have register disabled, and have attempted to do a IP based setup and a credential-based setup with no success. When doing the IP based setup I remove the user/pass field on Fusion and also remove the credential from the trunk termination on my Twilio console. When doing credential-based I add both back but in both scenarios I've made sure register is disabled.

Proxy is using this format: mytrunknamehere.pstn.twilio.com
Also tried the regionalized version. mytrunknamehere.pstn.us1.twilio.com

Don't really have any other settings configured on the trunk in FusionPBX.

Anyone happen to have a setup guide or advice?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the blog, [A Step-by-Step Guide to Set Up Twilio Elastic SIP Trunking](https://www.twilio.com/blog/elastic-sip-trunking-step-by-step-setup), and some of the troubleshooting steps presented there? Like looking at packet captures for Twilio's origination attempts toward your PBX (using Wireshark). Is your PBX responding and if so, with what SIP response coe? Also, what is the debug logging on your PBX showing, when you place a call into it via your Twilio phone number (similar with Termination, sending a call from your PBX into Twilio to deliver to the PSTN).

The key thing is trying to look below the surface to see who doesn't like what.

Comment: I was hoping someone had a configuration template/guide for FusionPBX to see if I was missing anything obvious. But that said I have looked at that blog entry but not helpful in resolving the situation. I'll have to give wireshark a go and see if I can resolve. I'm also evaluating another SIP provider and it connected right up. So I'll have to figure out why Twilio and Fusion are having a disagreement.